# How does or is it possible for a browser keep track of a pop up window

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I noticed when using the Google Chat feature from your Google Mail that you can pop out a chat into its' own window. Then when I went to close the Google Mail window it warned that other windows would also be closed if I continued and then showed a list of the windows. How is this done? Is it possible to track whether a window you invoked has been closed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, when you do a window.open in JavaScript, you can set it to a var like:

```
myWindow = window.open(...)
```

Then you could bind events to that window like:

```
myWindow.onUnload = funcWindowClosed;
```

You could keep track of multiple pop-up windows by putting them into an array.

You can also call JavaScript functions in the parent window by the child (pop-up) window using:

```
window.opener
```

Answer (score -2):

If you assign each new window a name when u make them a popup and then with php (or anything else) save the name of the window to a cookie or a session, you can then close all of the popups created by your site when a certain action is taken:

this is what i do (in php/js):

```
function closePopups(){
    var popups = Array();
    <?
    $i = 0;
    if(isset($_SESSION['popups'])){
        foreach($_SESSION['popups'] as $key=>$pop){
            echo "popups[$i] = '$pop';\n";
            $i++;
        }
        unset($_SESSION['popups']);
    }
?>
    for( i = 0; i < popups.length; i++ ){
        window.open('',popups[i],'width=1,height=1').close();
    }
}
```

In the for loop you have to open the popup first and then close it so that way your current window can see if a popup with that name was already opened, and if it was, than it will close it. If it wasn't it will create a new window with the same name and immediately close it.

This is how i soleved the issue

Comment: This doesn't let me check if they are open though. So you can't warn the user they're about to be closed

Comment: you can add on a confirm alert modal before the var popups to confirm whether or not they want to close the popups, and if they do, then run the rest of the function, else return to the page