# How to detect session time out in javascript in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, session

We have web application where we have one main window and after clicking on some link in this window it opens another screen in new window so there is one main window and could be multiple child screen now i want to  close all the screen when main window is closed on session time out ,how we can implement it ?

Basically i want to write a poller on main window for session time out.

Any suggestion?

Please let me know if question is not clear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just keep the reference of all child windows and close it when main window is closed. [Read more...](http://codesmiles.com/post/access-parent-window-from-child-window-or-access-child-window-from-parent-window-using-javascript.aspx)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171477/how-does-or-is-it-possible-E.g. for-a-browser-keep-track-of-a-pop-up-window